# Delete all rows except (my query)

Tags: t-sql

I've spent a bit of time looking for this situation and found many that are close but I can't get it to work with my situation.

To simplify, I have TABLE t with `contact_id` and `Code`

```
contact_id           Code
__________           ____
123456                100
123456                200
123456                300
987654                100
987654                200
654321                300
```

For each `contact_id` I want to select the row with the highest code and delete the others. I did come up with a select statement to show what I want the table to look like:

```
select distinct contact_id, MAX(code) OVER(Partition by contact_id) AS code
from t
```

Based on above then my result set is:

```
123456                300
987654                200
654321                300
```

How can I delete all rows except the ones produced by this select statement. I tried using a `NOT IN` clause but this of course will not support multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the rows wanted (in a variable or something), then delete the entire table, and then reinsert them as new rows.

Comment: Just a thought people, no need to hate on me. Besides, why must people make such minor, unneeded edits to posts? So annoying.

Comment: Under certain conditions (as a one-time batch job, large table with a small remaining data set), this may be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
with cte as
(
  select *
    , rownum = row_number() over (partition by contact_id order by code desc)
  from t
)
delete cte
where rownum <> 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36f77/6).

Comment: Brilliantly simple. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! If an answer helps solve your issue, please considering setting it as accepted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE atable
FROM atable at
INNER JOIN (    
   SELECT contact_id, code = MAX(code)
   FROM atable
   GROUP BY contact_id
) q ON at.contact_id = q.contact_id AND at.code < q.code
```

But if you have more than 1 row with the pair `contact_id + code` will produce more than 1 row per each contact_id.

Answer (score 0):

Without CTEs nor subqueries:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t t2
ON t1.contact_id = t2.contact_id AND t1.code < t2.code
WHERE t2.code IS NOT NULL;
```

Fiddle [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8f3d/1)